# How to avoid estimateRigidTransform returning None

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to use `estimateRigidTransform` to determine the transformation matrix between pairs of frames in a video. My problem is that nearly half of the pairs I feed the code return None values.

I've tried using the `estimateRigidTransform` with the whole frames, now I'm feeding points, and the result is slightly better, but still not good enough

```
############whole frames

frameBefore = cv2.imread("1.png")
frame = cv2.imread("result_00001.png") 
transform = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(frameBefore,frameafter, False)


###########data points

frameBefore = cv2.imread("1.png")
prev_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frameBefore, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
prev_pts = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(prev_gray,
                                     maxCorners=200,
                                     qualityLevel=0.01,
                                     minDistance=30,
                                     blockSize=3)
frame = cv2.imread("result_00001.png")
curr_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

curr_pts, status, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_gray, curr_gray, prev_pts, None) 
assert prev_pts.shape == curr_pts.shape

idx = np.where(status==1)[0]
prev_pts = prev_pts[idx]
curr_pts = curr_pts[idx]

transform = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(prev_pts, curr_pts, fullAffine=False)
```

For over 43000 frames, I get 18000 None values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This won't help, but cv2.estimateRigidTransform is deprecated in current versions of OpenCV in favor of  cv::estimateAffinePartial2D. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga762cbe5efd52cf078950196f3c616d48